# Google appengine/node/memcache failing with objects over ~3.5k - what am I missing?

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, memcached

I've have an app that works fine on my dev machine (osx, local memcached) but when I move it to appengine it fails.  I tracked it to memcache not storing objects over about 3.5k.

Here is a little test that runs under express. It takes a length value makes a buffers, sends it to memcache and tries to get it back.  It works fine locally up to the expected 1MB limit, however on appengine it fails at around length 3600 +/- 200 (it varies, which is really odd).  I've tried several different memcache libs, they all fail the same way.

```
//memcache test.
app.get('/mct/:len',function(req,res)  {
  var memcachedAddr = process.env.MEMCACHE_PORT_11211_TCP_ADDR || 'localhost';
  var memcachedPort = process.env.MEMCACHE_PORT_11211_TCP_PORT || '11211';
  var memcacheServer = memcachedAddr + ":" + memcachedPort;
  var Memcached = require('memcached');
  var client = new Memcached(memcacheServer);
  var len = req.params.len * 1; //lazy cast to int
  var text = new  Array(len + 1).join( " " );

  try {
    client.set("testkey",text,600,function(err,val) {
        client.get("testkey",function(err,data) {
            if (data && data.length === text.length) {
                res.send("OK at length " + text.length + " " +data.length);
            } else {
                res.send("Failed at " + text.length + " " );
            }
        });
    })
  } catch(e) {
    res.send("Failed at " + text.length + " " + e.message);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are sending to memcache a Buffer object, not string. I know nothing about the Buffer implementation on Node but I assume it can allocates more memory in advance then it actually require. For example in .NET usually it double the buffer size when it exceed the currently allocated limit.

Try to cast your buffer to string and store in memcache value as string. That should help.

Comment: Tried that, makes no difference.  Memcache should (and does) handle binary objects.